# why won't user login and password load next page in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2008, gridview, passwords

I am having trouble with my user login and password screen on a simple website I made. It is supposed to lead to a new page that shows an SQL source in grid view, but nothing happens when I press the submit button in the deployed website. Below is my code behind, along with the source for my default.aspx and my userAdmin.aspx. Is there something wrong with the code-behind? Please let me know if you can. Thanks!

```
   Protected Sub butSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butSubmit.Click

    Dim myReader As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    Dim mySqlConnection As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

    Dim mySqlCommand As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand


    'Establish the SqlConnection by using the configuration manager to get the connection string in our web.config file.

    mySqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString())

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT password FROM MyUsers WHERE username = '" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "'"

    mySqlCommand = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, mySqlConnection)



    Try

        mySqlConnection.Open()

        myReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()


        If (myReader.HasRows) Then

            myReader.Read()

            Dim password As String = myReader("password")

            If (password = Me.TextBox2.Text) Then

                'Open page with users and roles

                Dim message As String = "Correct password"

                Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly

                Dim title As String = "Authenticated"

                MsgBox(message, style, title)


            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())

    Finally

        If Not (myReader Is Nothing) Then

            myReader.Close()

        End If

        If (mySqlConnection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open) Then

            mySqlConnection.Close()

        End If

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

useradmin source

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/master.master" AutoEventWireup="false" title="UserAdmin" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="header" Runat="Server">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="navigation" Runat="Server">
<a href="Default.aspx">Default.aspx</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="userAdmin.aspx">userAdmin.aspx</a>
<br />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="main" Runat="Server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MyUsers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="UserRolesGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    Width="399px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_logon_id" HeaderText="user_logon_id" 
            SortExpression="user_logon_id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_full_name" HeaderText="user_full_name" 
            SortExpression="user_full_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_description" HeaderText="user_description" 
            SortExpression="user_description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_password" HeaderText="user_password" 
            SortExpression="user_password" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
 </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="footer" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

default.aspx source

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" MasterPageFile="~/master.master" AutoEventWireup="false"    CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" title="Untitled Page" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="header" Runat="Server">
<p style="text-align: center; color: white">
    SAM PEPPARD</p>
</asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="navigation" Runat="Server">
<a href="Default.aspx">Default.aspx</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="userAdmin.aspx">userAdmin.aspx</a>
<br />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="main" Runat="Server">
&nbsp &nbsp User Name
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Password&nbsp<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" 
    runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="butSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="footer" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After matching password you should redirect your browser to new page.

Use Response.Redirect(newpage)

Comment: so the redirect would go under like this?   

                MsgBox(message, style, title)
                                                            Response.Redirect(userAdmin.aspx)

Comment: I mean the Response.Redirect(userAdmin.aspx) would go under the MsgBox(message, style, title)?